# Got " merge incompatible" error when I use Gradle for an Android Application

Tags: android, gradle

I want to generate different apks for different channel,so the build.gradle is like:

```
productFlavors {
        playstore {

        }
        hip {

        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

         hip {
            manifest.srcFile 'hip/AndroidManifest.xml'
}
         playstore {
            manifest.srcFile 'hip/AndroidManifest.xml'
}
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

But when I build it ,I have got:

```
[AndroidManifest.xml:50, AndroidManifest.xml:50] Trying to merge incompatible /m
anifest/application/meta-data[@name=MobAd_CHANNEL] element:
  <meta-data
      @android:name="MobAd_CHANNEL"
--    @android:value="google market">
  <meta-data
      @android:name="MobAd_CHANNEL"
++    @android:value="hip">

:qingdaobus:processHipDebugManifest FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

So I an very confusion that I really want it different channel value

Answer (score 1):

If you only care of "playstore" and "hip" build, just define MobAd_CHANNEL in their own AndroidManifest.xml and don't defined in main/src/AndroidManifest.xml